# open lync chat window in javascript

Tags: javascript, sip, lync

I found the same question I'm about to ask on stackoverflow, but the answer didn't help as the link didn't deal with javascript as far as I can tell. [Is it possible to open a new Lync conversation from a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704811/is-it-possible-to-open-a-new-lync-conversation-from-a-webpage)

In a nutshell, I want to programmatically open a Lync chat window using javascript. I've done this with a simple link:

```
<a href="sip:person@domain.com">IM</a>
```

Clicking the link would open the window as expected. I'm looking for a way to duplicate that behavior in javascript:

```
function doImDeveloper() {
    //Javascript to open a Lync window
}
```

This is in an internal environment. I want people at my company to be able to click a button and have it launch a Lync conversation with me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for me.

```
window.location = "sip:person@domain.com"​
```

Comment: Weird...I thought I tried that, but I guess not. Thanks! That worked great.

Comment: I found that this worked fine for me in IE and Chrome on the desktop, but the URI scheme was not recognized by standard Web Browser for Android 4.4.2, nor by Chrome (39.0.2171.59) on Android.  So beware if you use this it won't be "mobile-ready".