# Microsoft Lync - Open IM Window With Message From Webpage

Tags: href, url-scheme, lync, lync-2013

Is it possible to open an IM window on Microsoft Lync from a webpage with a defined message? Something like:

```
<a href="im:?body=My Message">Lync</a>
```

The email equivalent would be:

```
<a href="mailto:?body=My Message">E-Mail</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to open a new Lync conversation from a webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704811/is-it-possible-to-open-a-new-lync-conversation-from-a-webpage)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can bring up the IM window, but you can't pre-define the message.

You bring up the IM with

```
<a href="im:<sip:someone@domain.com>">Go</a>
```

Ref: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg398376.aspx

Comment: This is cool, +1 for learning something new today! PS, also still works for the "Skype for Business" upgrade from Lync :)

Comment: Damn! I need a pre-populated message.